# Progress Dialog doesn't appear immediately

Tags: android, progressdialog

My progressDialog doesn't appear immediately when I start a new activity. I am using AsyncTask for the same. I am loading data from web service in next activity. Following is my async class :

```
private class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    Context con;
     Intent aboutusIntent;
     TabGroupActivity parentActivity;
    private TheTask(Context context)
    {
        this.con=context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(con, "Loading... ",
                "please wait....", true);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         aboutusIntent = new Intent(con, Departments.class);
          parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
        //progDialog.show();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        parentActivity.startChildActivity("Departments", aboutusIntent);
        if(progDialog.isShowing())
        {
        progDialog.dismiss();
        }


    }

}
```

I am creating instance of this class onClick of button :

```
ourdepbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new TheTask(AboutUs.this.getParent()).execute();
        }
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();// This statement is to be called by the main thread  

ProgressDialog.show();// This statement is to be called by the main thread  

Thread t = new Thread(  
new Runnable(){  

public void run()  
{  

  callWebServicesHereAndFetchingMethod(); //  

   mHandler.post(new Runnable(){  

   public void run()  
   {  
     ProgressDialog.dismiss();  
   }   
});  
    }});  
t.start();
```

Comment: I am using tab group in this application. So does this has anything to do with it? Because when i place startActivity in doInBackground() , the progressDialog appears but allication crashes. I encounter a FutureTaskError.

Comment: This thing has nothing to do with tab group. Its just that all visual effects are to be controlled by Main Thread only..A single thread can do either fetching or show any progress in the dialog. Handler class is basically used for this . The code i pasted i used it in all my projects and it is working best to show any fetching progress using Dialogs.  If any thread except the Main thread try to implement any visual effect  . this will crash the app with exception

Comment: Your suggestion is working almost correctly. The only proble is that the result is shown correctly when i debug the application, but on running the application only dialog appears but not the result.What might be the reason?

Comment: Check your network connectivity ... size of your data buffer must be zero. this has nothing to do with debugging and running.. if code runs in debugging it  will run in running mode as well.

Comment: Use log events to see the problem

Comment: The code inside public void run() is not implementing.Only the handler part is running.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code Need Multithreading .... All the Visual Effect is controlled by your main thread. If you do any processing or say data fectching from web services using Main thread then progress dialog will not appear . 
Make the progress dialog show function called by the Main Thread. do all the fetching using another thread.  make a thread that will join your fetching thread and Using Handler class object produce any visual effect you want to do

If you need this to be elaborated more. i will post that too

Comment: Yes Javanator.I'll appriciate if you can put an example for what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

The user interface (UI) is not thread safe, calls to the UI must be made from the main thread (also called the "UI thread").

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); // Create on main thread.

// ...

handler.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
       "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is AsyncTask, where you can show/hide the ProgressDialog in onPreExecute()/onPostExecute()

You can read more about it [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask)